# Whata bytes are removed while resizing with QFile().resize(qint64)?

Tags: qt, qt4

Can anyone please tell me ... 
I want to remove last bytes from a file .
So resizing this with help of resize () will resize the file size but what bytes will be removed ??
I have int count ,
 I want to remove 'count' bytes from last of the file...

What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

quoted from the documentation of `QFile::resize` (emphasis mine)

> Sets the file size (in bytes) sz. Returns true if the file if the
>   resize succeeds; false otherwise. If sz is larger than the file
>   currently is the new bytes will be set to 0, **if sz is smaller the file
>   is simply truncated.**
>
> See also size() and setFileName().

truncated means that the last bytes are dropped